# How to properly use TemplatesServiceClient google-cloud-dataflow

Tags: java, spring, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm fairly new to google cloud and even more so with google cloud dataflow. I have created a java application with the sole purpose of running a dataflow job. The details are as follows:

First I create a bean with the following properties:

```
@Bean(name="dataflowTemplateJobConfigMap")
public Map<DataflowTemplateJob, DataflowTemplateConfig> dataflowTemplateJobConfigMap(
        @Value("${job.gcs.export.gcs.path}") String gcsExportGcsPath,
        @Value("${job.gcs.export.bigtable.project.id}") String gcsExportBigtableProjectId,
        @Value("${job.gcs.export.bigtable.instance.id}") String gcsExportBigtableInstanceId,
        @Value("${job.gcs.export.bigtable.table.id}") String gcsExportBigtableTableId,
        @Value("${job.gcs.export.output.directory}") String gcsExportOutputDirectory,
        @Value("${job.gcs.export.filename.prefix}") String gcsExportFilenamePrefix,
        @Value("${job.gcs.export.num.shards}") String gcsExportNumShards) {
    Map<DataflowTemplateJob, DataflowTemplateConfig> configMap = new HashMap<>();

    // gcs-export job
    DataflowTemplateConfig gcsExportConfig = new DataflowTemplateConfig();
    gcsExportConfig.setGcsPath(gcsExportGcsPath);
    gcsExportConfig.setParameterMap(ImmutableMap.<String, String>builder()
            .put("bigtableProjectId", gcsExportBigtableProjectId)
            .put("bigtableInstanceId", gcsExportBigtableInstanceId)
            .put("bigtableTableId", gcsExportBigtableTableId)
            .put("outputDirectory", gcsExportOutputDirectory)
            .put("filenamePrefix", gcsExportFilenamePrefix)
            .put("numShards", gcsExportNumShards)
            .build());
    configMap.put("GCS_EXPORT", gcsExportConfig);

    return configMap;
}
```

What does a DataflowTemplateConfig look like you ask?

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class DataflowTemplateConfig {
    private String gcsPath;
    private Map<String, String> parameterMap;
}
```

Then I just have a run method:

```
@Value("${google.cloud.project.id}")
private String projectId;

@Value("${google.cloud.region}")
private String region;

@Resource(name="dataflowTemplateJobConfigMap")
private Map<DataflowTemplateJob, DataflowTemplateConfig> dataflowTemplateConfigMap;

public Job run(DataflowTemplateJob dataflowTemplateJob) throws IOException {
    DataflowTemplateConfig config = dataflowTemplateConfigMap.get(dataflowTemplateJob);
    try (TemplatesServiceClient templatesServiceClient =TemplatesServiceClient.create()) {
        CreateJobFromTemplateRequest request =
                CreateJobFromTemplateRequest.newBuilder()
                        .setProjectId(projectId)
                        .setJobName(dataflowTemplateJob.getJobName())
                        .putAllParameters(config.getParameterMap())
                        .setEnvironment(RuntimeEnvironment.newBuilder().build())
                        .setLocation(region)
                        .setGcsPath(config.getGcsPath())
                        .build();
        Job response = templatesServiceClient.createJobFromTemplate(request);
        jobRepository.addJob(response);
        return response;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to start Dataflow job", e);
    }
}
```

When I run the job, via command line, typically the job successfully starts but always fails. And the first time I ran it I got the following error:

```
{
insertId: "6e9nqud4qhu"
labels: {4}
logName: "projects/test/test-dataflow/logs/dataflow.googleapis.com%2Fjob-message"
receiveTimestamp: "2023-05-06T00:56:00.125700767Z"
resource: {2}
severity: "ERROR"
textPayload: "Error processing pipeline."
timestamp: "2023-05-06T00:55:59.103993244Z"
}
```

Mind you I'd been trying for a while and got my service-account and workload-identity set up correctly before ever even getting the job to run at all. Anyways I'm looking into the recommended documentation but has anyone used TemplatesServiceClient? If so can you link your git repo? I just want to rule out that this is a code related issue and that it is actually on the service-account/workload-identity side. If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated! Hope this is enough information.

Oh and here is some documentation to TemplatesServiceClient in case you're unfamiliar/unsure: https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-cloud-dataflow/latest/overview#templatesserviceclient
This is the specific template I'm using: gs://dataflow-templates/2023-04-11-00_RC00/Cloud_Bigtable_to_GCS_Parquet

Answer (score 0):

Ok so looking deeper into the dataflow api it turns out there are a few more fields we want to include in our CreateJobFromTemplateRequest. They are: IpConfiguration, Network, SubNetwork, and ServiceAccount. Here is what the code change looks like:

```
CreateJobFromTemplateRequest request =
                CreateJobFromTemplateRequest.newBuilder()
                        .setProjectId(projectId)
                        .setJobName(dataflowTemplateJob.getJobName())
                        .putAllParameters(parameterMap)
                        .setEnvironment(RuntimeEnvironment.newBuilder()
                                .setIpConfiguration(WorkerIPAddressConfiguration.WORKER_IP_PRIVATE)
                                .setNetwork(network)
                                .setSubnetwork(subnetwork)
                                .setServiceAccountEmail(serviceAccountEmail)
                                .build())
                        .setLocation(region)
                        .setGcsPath(config.getGcsPath())
                        .build();
```

This should get the job running and even finish the job.